# I have a css drop down menu that disappears

Tags: css

I have a (css) drop down menu that keeps disappearing before you can select anything from it.

I have wracked my brain searching the web for answers... and in an article on YOUR site I found a hint -- about z-index.. I readily admit to being quite a NOOB when it comes to CSS and I tried and tried to implement the suggestion from your other article, but to no avail.

Here is my site: http://www.customernationonline.com/

The problem is with the drop down for "How We Help".. I would be hugely grateful if you could take a look and help me out here.

Comment: What browser are you using I just tried in FF 4.0 and it works fine

Comment: @John, I am using FF4 also and if I move the mouse fast it works, but slow it drops out.

Comment: On my site? I didn't know I have a site. ([/sarcasm] Which site?)

Answer (score 2):

The (eloquent) fix was hard to find, (it took me a while to figure out, at any rate!), but it's very easy:

- On `#pillmenu2`, remove `position: absolute`.

Comment: Then I discovered that once the user logged in, the pillmenu2 menu would never display... I actually finally fixed this by putting a z-index:1 on pillmenu2 and a higher z-index on pillmenu

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the mouse out on the menu item is closing the dropdown

sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
39 this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\b"), "");
40 }

perhaps close the menu item only with an onclick command either when a sub menu item is selected or on the body. better still look at the jquery implementations and save yourself a headache.