# Menu column disappears before I can click on it?

Tags: css

It's a problem similar to [I have a css drop down menu that disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997805/i-have-a-css-drop-down-menu-that-disappears) but the solutions aren't working for me. The drop menu disappears before I can click on it. It works better on Firefox but only if you move the cursor quickly.

Any ideas?

The entire menu container (so, the link on the nav bar + the links that appear when you hover) is at a z-index of 1, if that's any help.

Also, to make this menu I followed this tutorial very closely: http://youhack.me/2011/09/18/how-to-build-a-drop-down-menu-enhanced-with-css3/

Thank you!

You're right, Scott, here's the code:

HTML code

```
    <nav>
<ul>
    <li style="background-color: #AECC4C;"><a href="">Home</a>
     </li>
    <li><a href="">How It Works</a>
    <div class="menu-container-1">
        <div class="column-1">
        <a href="">Submenu 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column-1">
        <a href="">Submenu 2</a>
        </div>                                              
     </div>
     </li>
    <li><a href="">Post Here</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Blog</a>
        <div class="menu-container-2">
            <div class="column-1">
                <a href="">Articles</a>
            </div>
            <div class="column-1">
                <a href="">Related links</a>
            </div>                                          
         </div></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li style="text-decoration:underline"><a href="">Donate!</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS code

```
    .menu-container-1, .menu-container-2 {
z-index: 1;
margin:10px auto;
float:left;
position:absolute;
left:-999em;
text-align:left;
padding:10px 5px;
border:1px dotted #b7b7b7;
border-top:none;
background:#ffffff;
    }

    .column-1, .column-2 {
display:inline;
float:left;
position:relative;
margin:2px 5px;
     }

      .column-1 a, .column-1 a:visited {
display: block; /* this gives the link block properties causing it to fill the whole LI containing it. This causes the entire area to react to a mouse click. */
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
        -o-transition: all .2s ease;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    .column-1 a:hover, .column-1 a:focus {
color: #EB6110;
     }

    nav li:hover .menu-container-1 {
left:170px;
width: 120px;
    }

    nav li:hover .menu-container-2 {
left:450px;
width: 100px;

    }
```

Comment: What would be of help is for you to post some of your relevant html and css code.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem as a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), or provide a link to your broken page?

Comment: Hi guys, here's a link to jsFiddle demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/LfexE/embedded/result/

and with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/LfexE/

In my version there's a little less space between the nav and drop menu but it basically has the same problem. Make sure to see it in full screen to get the idea. 
THanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to explicitly declare the top distance of the menu containing divs:

```
nav li:hover .menu-container-1 {
 top: 11px;
 left:150px;
 width: 120px;
}

nav li:hover .menu-container-2 {
 top: 11px;
 left:420px;
 width: 100px;
}
```

If your menu item heights are all static, this should do the trick.

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LfexE/1/

Comment: Thanks, Todd, that did the trick! Embarrassed but relieved that it was such a simple solution :)